Video editor to easily create an instant movie of images
I'm looking for an application (better for Linux, or Windows) to easily and quickly create an instant movie of images that is able to also add effects, transitions and music in a few clicks. It'd be better to be a local desktop app, so no online web-based tools, for privacy purposes.
I have Adobe Premiere Elements 2025 that is able to create a video of images with music, but it applies always the same transitions, no zoom or other random effects on the images, and I should manually edit it after.
Now there are a lot of AI tools, I have Ollama, Gpt4all, LM Studio and others, but none of them is able to create videos of images, it would be nice to have something AI-based to do that locally on my system!
Any suggestion?
Thanks
